# Asterisk keeps confusing public and private IPs so calls have no audio when softphones are behind NAT

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, rtp, nat

I'm trying to set up a voip system using asterisk and custom made mobile apps to make calls between users.
The system works perfectly when set up on the same network, but once deployed on the online server due to the fact that Softphones are behind NAT, audio is not going through but all SIP packets are properly received and softphones ring but when a call is open, no audio is heard on both endpoints.
I've looked everywhere about how to set up asterisk to work with endpoints behind NAT, but everything online talks about sip on the older versions of Asterisk. But i'm using the latest version of Asterisk which is using Pjsip.conf, i've tried different settings for the endpoints but RTP still confuses the IPs and tries to route the RTP packets to the private IP instead of the public IP.
I've tried rewrite_contact, direct_media, force_rport, ice_support, rtp_symmetric with different options, don't seem to find the perfect setting.

Has anyone done this before? do you have any documentation that i can look at for the latest versions of Asterisk?

Comment: apparently it's not anything that needs to be done on the asterisk deployment. It was a client issue, the client sip phone needs to have RPORT for media enabled and I was using MizuDroid which did not have that feature. Once I switched to Zoiper and set that option on, everything started working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's not anything that needs to be done on the asterisk deployment. It was a client issue, the client sip phone needs to have RPORT for media enabled and I was using MizuDroid which did not have that feature. Once I switched to Zoiper and set that option on, everything started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your transport of pjsip (type=transport used by your extensions) you have to set local_net, external_media_address, external_signaling_address :

```
[transport-udp-nat]
type = transport
protocol = udp
bind = 0.0.0.0
local_net = (your local network like 192.168.0.0/24)
external_media_address = (your external IP)
external_signaling_address = (your external IP)
```

Also, you have to use in your extensions:

```
rewrite_contact = yes
direct_media = no 
force_rport = yes
rtp_symmetric = yes
```